# Grid vs Flex for implementations of Holy Grail-like layout

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid, grid-layout

I want my layout to go from this when `Sidebar` is present:

[image]

To this when `Sidebar` is not present:

[image]

To get this effect, I believe three modern choices are to:

1. Grid alone: have a `grid` that utilizes a `class` like this https://codepen.io/rajsinghusa/pen/ExPaXqR , or
2. Grid+Flex: have a `grid` layout for 3 rows, with two `flex` items for
   the middle row. Or,
3. Flex alone: use `flex` to create 3 rows and then two columns in
   the middle row.

How would these three implementations differ in their limitations?

Comment: flex & grid would require a différent structure , that's where you'll make a choice following your own document semantics. flex & grid are different not better one to the other.

Comment: This not the place to ask such question. We don't do discussion here. It's about programming issues: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Given your implementation details, I would say that the only difference is semantic. The three options will work well, for your use-case I think the `grid` is the one I would go since it's easy to see what's happening on the different layouts.

Looking side by side at both declarations its very clear how the layout works:

```
"header header" "sidebar main" "footer footer"
"header header" "main main" "footer footer"
```

I don't see a clear benefit in using options 2 or 3 given this use-case.

An important thing to have in mind is how grid behaves compared to flex:

> **Grid is Container-Based, Flexbox is Content-Based**
>
> In flexbox layout, the size of a cell (flex-item) is defined inside the flex-item itself,
>   and in the grid layout, the size of a cell (grid-item) is defined
>   inside the grid-container.

Source: https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2018/09/grid-vs-flexbox-which-should-you-choose/

Depending on how you want your layout to behave, how it adapts to different screen resolutions or different content this difference is good to have in mind. Again I think `grid` will give more options in this regard.